# Reputation on math SE and math meta differ by 12K points

Tags: bug, reputation, per-site-meta

My reputation on Math SE and Meta Math SE differ by almost 12,000 points. I know the meta rep only updates every once in awhile, but I was pretty sure it is every day. It's been almost a year since my reputation was 36K.

[image]

Comment: Its pretty strange that MathMeta has its own entry on the "Your Communities" list. MSO doesn't has one in my list. Anyway, when checking your profile both rep points are equal.

Comment: @Tom it's possible to add per-site metas to that list, if you maintain it manually.

Comment: @Glorfindel You're right, I just checked it and I also get different rep points. It looks like that list as a different caching, maybe a much higher one for meta sites (except MSE).

Comment: @Glorfindel It's a similar issue, but the answer certainly doesn't answer my question. (I know it's an auto comment.)

Comment: It's the same issue, and I thought it was solved by the reputation recalculation (it's my answer there), but that was only temporary.

Comment: @Glorfindel The reputation recalculation happened when I had probably around 46K rep. Like I said, 36K rep was about a year ago.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I see a comment under my answer by another user who didn't get recalculated either.